# Are pointers with the MSB set (i.e.holding negative values) always invalid under Win64?

Tags: pointers, assembly, 64-bit, win64

I'm rewriting some fast string functions.
The goal of this exercise is to eliminate jumps so as to avoid misprediction.
This code only runs in user space.

Do Win64 pointers always evaluate to a positive Int64 value?

```
function BothValid(a,b: pointer): boolean;
// a= rcx
// b= rdx
asm
  lea    rax, [rcx-4]
  lea    r8,  [rdx-4]
  or     r8,  rax
  js @OneOrMoreNullPointers 
  ....
```

**Is the above way of testing for null pointers always valid?**

Comment: Because the universe will probably be dead by the time you can actually utilize them?

Comment: In 64 bit mode address must be canonical, i.e. sign extended. So if interpreted as 64 bit signed number, they may be negative. Anyway to test if one of the operand is 0 I would have used and AND. why if the SF is set one pointer must be null?

Comment: @knm241, because 0-4 is negative. 0 being a `null pointer`,

Comment: Ah got it. isn't AND more suitable?

Comment: @knm241, try and use `and` without using extra jmp's or more instructions.

Comment: Well, `AND` is obviously not a solution, but x86 has widening multiplies. `a*b` is zero if and only if at least one of the operands is zero.

Comment: addresses are addresses they cant be negative, they are just bits.   Dont make assumptions about the future based on some convention used today.

Comment: I would have used `AND` with `TEST` and `SETNZ`. 5 instructions and no jumps as the question title asked.

Comment: @knm241, replace the `js` with `sets`, 4 instructions and no jumps.

Comment: You are the only one with the final judging as you are the only one knowing what you want (e.g. I don't know why you consider a pointer with values 0x0..0x3 a null pointer) but I will happily spend one more instruction for the sake of compatibility. *Both version of the code perform similarly, performance is not a matter of instructions number anymore*. Windows already passed from a "always positive pointers" (2GiB limit) to a "not always positive pointers" (3GiB). This is unlikely to happen again in the near future, but again... all this for an (irrelevant) instruction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, found the relevant link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> For a 32-bit process, the virtual address space is usually the 2-gigabyte range 0x00000000 through 0x7FFFFFFF. **For a 64-bit process, the virtual address space is the 8-terabyte range 0x000'00000000 through 0x7FF'FFFFFFFF**.
>
> portions of the 248-terabyte range from 0xFFFF0800'00000000 through 0xFFFFFFFF'FFFFFFFF are used for system space.
>
> Code running in user mode has access to user space but does not have access to system space.

In 32 bit you can increase the size of user space to 3 gigabytes maximum; in that case user space pointers can have negative int values.

So yes, user space pointers in Win64 are always positive numbers.
Kernel space pointers are always negative numbers.

Comment: Hmm, 20 years ago it used to say "is always" instead of "is usually".  Will history repeat itself?  Doesn't it usually?  Doesn't it always?